# Bayes rule clarification

Tags: probability

According to my book it states [image]

[image]

The only thing i'm not clear is the partition. When it states let events $B_1,...,B_n$ be a partition of all possible outcomes does that mean it does not have to necessarily partition the sample space because the book partitions the first event that happens which may not necessarily partition the sample space I think? For example let the sample space $\xi=\{(\text{truck#1 is not driven, breaks}), (\text{truck#2 is not driven, works}), (\text{truck#1 is  driven, breaks}), (\text{truck#2 is  driven, works}\}$.

Suppose we want to calculate that what is the chance that truck #1 is driven given that a truck is selected and it won't break. So the first event is picking the truck denoted my T. We can either pick $T_1$ or $T_2$ which is a partition of $T$ but not the sample space. Further let $B^c$ stand for the event the truck does not break. So $T\cap B^c$=$(T_1\cap B^c)\cup (T_2\cap B^c)$ is partition for $T$ but not for the sample space. I'm not sure if i'm on the right track here. Thanks

Comment: You are on the correct track. Partition need not be of the whole space.

Answer (score 2):

Sample space is specifically defined for each random experiment/trial.

> The sample space of an experiment or random trial is the set of all
>   possible outcomes or results of that experiment.

It is not a set of all possible outcomes of all random experiments, which means it is not the whole space. (I'm afraid you have some misunderstanding on this definition.)

Therefore, a sample space for $T$ is the set of all possible outcomes of experiment $T$.

> A partition of a set X is a division of X as a union of
>   non-overlapping and non-empty subsets

Therefore, when the book say

> a partition of all the outcomes (of B)

it implies

> a partition of the sample space of B